# How to handle the consume of call PUT with Mulesoft

Tags: mule-studio, mule-component

I 'd like to know how to handle and to design the flow to consume three sequential calls type PUT with muleSoft. I 'll enter from main flow by VM Connector and I insert HTTP connector to consume PUT with data in payload. To handle the errors if the first, second and third request PUT response unsuccessful (example status code 400),Where can I handle it? Must I another flow? how can I do?

Above I have already done Flow call Request Put
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will have the same request for all 3 outbound call that you are calling sequentially , what you can do is

1. just after the VM inbound save your request in a variable, then call
   the first HTTP call as you are doing.
2. After the HTTP outbound call for first service, set the  payload with your variable and call your second service using another HTTP
3. Same steps as step 2 you follow for your 3rd call

Regarding exception, you can check here for handling https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Catch+Exception+Strategy

And to control `HTTP status code`, if you are using Mule 3.6+ version, you can easily control `HTTP status code` with your `http:request` component as given here with **Status Code Validator**:-  https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/HTTP+Request+Connector